# Mapping Double nested JSON - Object not allowed in React Child

Tags: reactjs

I have a json file that looks like this:

```
"skills":[
      {
        "type":"Languages",
        "skill":[
          {
            "name":"Python"
          },
          {
            "name":"Java"
          },
          {
            "name":"JavaScript"
          },
          {
            "name":"HTML"
          },
          {
            "name":"Bash"
          },
          {
            "name":"MySQL"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Flavours",
        "skill": [
          {
            "name":"Reactjs"
          },
          {
            "name":"Angularjs"
          },
          {
            "name":"Agile"
          },
          {
            "name":"Waterfall"
          },
          {
            "name":"Kanban"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Technologies",
        "skill": [
          {
            "name":"Jira"
          },
          {
            "name":" BitBucket"
          },
          {
            "name":"Git"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
```

And i am trying to render it using a nested mapping function:

```
var skills = this.props.data.skills.map((skills) =>{
  var skill = skills.skill.map(function(skill){
    return <li key={skill.name}>{skill}</li>
  })
  return <ul key={skills.type}>{skills}</ul>
})
```

However it says "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

So i tried it like this:

```
      var skills = this.props.data.skills.map(function(skills){
        var skillsArr = []
        var skill = skills.skill.map(function(skill){
          var skillArr = []
          skillArr.push(<li key={skill.name}>{skill}</li>)
          return <span>{skillArr}</span>
        })
        skillsArr.push(<div key={skills.type}><h3>{skills.type}</h3>
          <ul>
            {skill}
          </ul>
        </div>);
        return <div>{skillsArr}</div>
      })
```

But this too gives me the exact same error, i dont get what is wrong here because if i do a single mapping of just the skill types it works, it is only when i try to render the inner mapped items does this error occur and break my code

This is how i am calling it btw:

```
<div className="bars">
    <ul className="skills">
       {skills}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are talking about using React, you should think more about how to organize your code in order to follow a proper component structure, that will let clear what you want to render and how to properly split your data and responsibilities.

Looking to your JSON, we have a set of "skills" that have skills inside it (let's call them "innerSkills").

We can easily split it into 3 components, let's think together:

We can have a `List` that will render all your `Skills`.

We can have a `Skill` that will be responsible for rendering each `Skill` data, inside it, we will need to render the `InnerSkills`, so let's split it to another component.

We have then `InnerSkill`, that will be responsible for rendering each `innerSkill` that we have for each `skill`.

So, long story short, what we have is:

`List -> Skill -> InnerSkills`

Great, now that we established the split, let's see how we can make each component responsible for rendering its data.

Let's say we want to simply call `<List skills={data} />`. Following this, we can then start on the list itself, which would look something like:

```
const List = ({ skills }) => (
  <ul>
    {skills.map((skill, i) => (
      <Skill key={i} skill={skill} />
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

Now that we are looping through all `Skills` and calling the `Skill` component for rendering it, we can take a look at how `Skill` should look, since it will also need to loop through `skill`.

```
const Skill = ({ skill }) => (
  <li>
    <p>Type: {skill.type}</p>
    <ul>
      {skill.skill.map((innerSkill, i) => (
        <InnerSkill key={i} innerSkill={innerSkill} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  </li>
);
```

Great. Now we already have the two loops you need to render all the data, so it's just missing the definition on how each `InnerSkill` should look like, and we can take a simplified approach and say we just want to render the name, so it could be something like:

```
const InnerSkill = ({ innerSkill }) => (
  <li>
    <p>Name: {innerSkill.name}</p>
  </li>
);
```

To summarize this implementation, I made a simple code sandbox so you can [**See it live!**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-forked-fwxfj?file=/index.js) and play around with the components.

I hope this clarifies your question and helps you to think better in the future on how you want to organize stuff, first check how to split, later how to render. Don't try to start rendering everything inside loops because it will get nasty.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things in your code causing this error:

```js
var skills = this.props.data.skills.map((skills) =>{
  var skill = skills.skill.map(function(skill){
    // should be <li key={skill.name}>{skill.name}</li>
    return <li key={skill.name}>{skill}</li>
  })

  // should be <ul key={skills.type}>{skill}</ul>
  return <ul key={skills.type}>{skills}</ul>
})
```

Assuming you want a single unordered list of all skill names, I'd suggest using the [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) function to re-write this as follows:

```
<div className="bars">
  <ul className="skills">
    {this.props.data.skills.flatMap((skillGroup) =>
      skillGroup.skill.map((skill) => (
        <li key={skill.name}>{skill.name}</li>
      ))
    )}
  </ul>
</div>
```